# Xubuntu system broken after copying files

Tags: linux, rescue, system-recovery

I was trying to copy files from one directory to another while keeping permissions for the files. The files in question where part of a rootfs built for armhf as I was trying to get 14.04 to run on my ASUS TF201. Problem is that while copying the files I seem to have copied the files into my installation somehow (no idea how that happened). Long story short my system now has all kinds of problems. System errors left and right and trouble with getting internet and mounting disks. Is there any way to fix this? I have a live USB (which I'm booting from right now to write this) and I was hoping there was some kind of recovery option bit I can't seem to find any.

The script in question is http://pastebin.com/rbjQ7nad which reads from a file which contains file entries to copy over.